# Are there some base64 strings that are encoded and decoded a human readable string?

Tags: base64

I found in old code a sequence, that checks wether a string is base64-encoded or not.

I think it is impossible to check that, so I want to explain some people (no real programmers) that is impossible.
For that I need some example strings that are base64 encoded and are also "real" words.

Comment: If a string is A-Z,a-z,1-9and +/, and isn't otherwise meaningful, it's a fair bet it's base64. If it has trailing = to pad it out to a multiple of 3 bytes, it becomes practically certain. You can usually spot plaintext when you see it too, though rigid rules are hard to define.

Comment: The Problem ist, that you can't say that "abc" is base64-encoded or not. So I want to explan that to other people, that are not programmers.